# Debugging Redis/Jedis performance issues

Tags: linux, networking, redis

I have an application that currently has an in-memory cache and, of course, the performance is blazing fast. But due to some reasons (that are out of scope here) I want to start using Redis but the performance has dropped drastically.

I have a couple dozen instances, each running nginx and a Java app. `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` has been bumped to `10240 65535` so that there are 64,000 ports available for nginx to talk to the app.  With the in-memory cache, the environment can easily support some 10,000 RPS and the app would be utilizing some 45-50% of the CPU. With Redis, I'm only getting 2500 RPS and the CPU utilization isn't crossing even 10%. The Redis cluster is already configured to support tens of thousands of clients but my app isn't actually making more than a couple hundred connections total -- it always seems to be 8 connections per instance. I am using the Jedis driver and the `maxTotal` property is set to 200, so I'm expecting to see (200)*(~25 instances) = ~5000 connections.

How do I go about debugging this? What should I do for my app to create more connections to Redis?